# recommendations for runtime configuration of backend API url in Angular 2 application

Tags: angular, angular-cli

This has been bugging me for a while and it seems that every other week, I come up with a different set of pros and cons.

The gist of it is that a good SPA is split into 2 different parts. The front-end and the back-end. The front-end should only be about static files (javascript, css, html, etc.) while the back-end serves the actual data and is dynamic.
However, the **one piece that I always seem to want dynamic with the front-end is the back-end URL**.

What I mean is that I usually serve my app off let's say `http://server:123/` and my API from `http://other:456/api`. Frequently, `other` and `server` are the same and the ports change, but as we scale, this is not always the case.

So, my question is: **what are the best practices for providing configuration data to an Angular 2 application?**

Here is what I thought of already:

**proxy**

Most web servers, even the mostly static-content-oriented ones, offer some sort of proxy configuration (nginx, angular-cli serve, etc.).
The problem with the proxy is that the request does do a double-hop. It first must be sent to the *static* server and then that server must turn around and make the real request.
I am not a fan of this architecture, though I did use it in the past on other applications.

**configuration file**

This is currently my favorite. I pretty much serve a static file (let's say `/config.json`) off my static-content server which contains one or more URL or other non-sensitive information.
I like this approach because it allows you to use a proxy, or *not*. It's up to you.
Most of the time, it is pretty simple to configure your web server to return a static file based on a url (let's say `/config`).

**code configuration**

This is my least favorite. In this approach, the configuration is written directly into a code file (`config.ts` for example) and has to be changed for each environment. I consider code and configuration to be 2 different tasks and in most of the company I have worked with, they are handled by 2 different teams.
It would be silly to have to recompile your code and redeploy just to change your back-end URL.

Comment: I'm facing the same dilemma right now - using a CI server to deploy to staging / production.

How did you end up solving your problem ?

Comment: @RVandersteen, I went with the configuration file. We use `nginx` to serve our data and `Chef` to deploy to our various environments (think QA, Staging, etc.). This made it easy to change API URLs.

Comment: Thanks - So you have a static config.json file and then a Angular 2 service that fetches it and set's the values I assume. Do you do this on bootstrap or when required

Comment: @RVandersteen, correct. From your Angular code, you always hit `/config` or whatever URL you want. Then you have to let your back-end fetch that file. Technically, you can simply have a `config.json` file and have hit your `/config.json` URL. However, I don't find this as clean. It reveals more than I am comfortable with.

Comment: I faced this dilemma as well, I wonder why it isn't a hot topic nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

I used configuration files but prefer setting environment variables by DevOps tools.

With containers, for simpler configuration, I use environment variables. Otherwise I pass configuration of a back-end config store, like Redis or now a days Kube Secrets (easier to use).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but if you want to use the configuration file approach, you can use my library [angular-runtime-config](https://github.com/vdolek/angular-runtime-config#readme) for runtime configuration loading for Angular.

**Simple usage example**

Your custom `Configuration` class:

```
export class Configuration {
  readonly apiUrl!: string; // only example
  readonly apiKey?: string; // only example
  // add some other configuration parameters
}
```

Registering [angular-runtime-config](https://github.com/vdolek/angular-runtime-config#readme) module with declaring which configuration files to load. For example, you can determine it by application URL or you can even use Angular injector in the factory or make the factory asynchronous.

```
import { AngularRuntimeConfigModule } from 'angular-runtime-config';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularRuntimeConfigModule.forRoot(Configuration, {
      urlFactory: () => [ 'config/config.common.json', 'config/config.DEV.json' ]
    })
  ],
}
```

Then request your `Configuration` class in any injection context.

```
@Injectable({...})
export class SomeService {
  constructor(private readonly config: Configuration) {}
}
```